# Simplify method retrieving data from generic repository

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a method that retrieves data from different repositories based on given arguments.

```
private async Task<string> GetByIdFrom(EntityArgs args)
{
    string content = null;
    switch (args.CollectionName.ToLowerInvariant())
    {
        case Common.WorkingSite:
            var workingsite = await (new Repository<WorkingSite>())
                .GetByKeyAsync(args.Id);
            if (workingsite != null)
                content = workingsite.Content;
            break;
        case Common.ProductInstruction:
            var productInfo = await (new Repository<ProductInstruction>())
                .GetByKeyAsync(args.Id);
            if (productInfo != null)
                content = productInfo.Content;
            break;
        case Common.Resource:
            var resource = await (new Repository<Resource>())
                .GetByKeyAsync(args.Id);
            if (resource != null)
                content = resource.Content;
            break;
        default:
            Logger.Warn("GetById(): Table {0} not found", args.CollectionName);
            break;
    }
    return content;
}
```

As you can see the `switch` is all about repetition and all `cases` return `Content` by `args.Id` if `EntityArgs` are valid. Content is always complex JSON.

The `CollectionName` property is `string` because request is coming from JavaScript client; `CollectionName` simply identifies `SQLite` table on .NET parts.

All of the above classes for `Repository<T>` implements same abstract base `Entity`.

```
[JsonObject]
public abstract class Entity
{
    protected Entity()
    {}

    [PrimaryKey]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Repository is implemented as follows, where `SQLiteDataProvider` is wrapper around `SQLite-net` ORM, connected to local `SQLite` database.

```
public class Repository<T> where T : new()
{
    private readonly Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    /// <summary>
    /// Get by primary key
    /// </summary>
    public virtual async Task<T> GetByKeyAsync(object key)
    {
        var item = default(T);

        try
        {
            item = await SQLiteDataProvider.Connection.GetAsync<T>(key);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if ((e is InvalidOperationException) && e.Message.Contains("no elements"))
            {
                _logger.Info("GetByKeyAsync<{0}> - {1}", (typeof(T)).Name, e.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.Error(e);
                throw;    
            }
        }
        return item;
    }

    // ...other methods
}
```

I'm pretty sure I should be able to get rid of whole `switch` statement and just call something like

```
var item = await (new Repository<Entity>()).GetByKeyAsync(args.Id);
return item != null ? item.Content : null;
```

...of course above won't work since I need to know the concrete class that corresponds underlying database table.

I just can't get my head around it. Ideas?

Comment: the original code seems clear -- why would you want to do this?

Comment: Lot's of reasons. One is unit testing where I'd like to pass in mock for just  Repository<T>.

Answer (score 1):

Sicne all your types implement `Entity`, you can make a generic method that requires the type argument to inherit from it so you can access the `Content` property.

```
private async Task<string> GetByIdFrom<T>(EntityArgs args)
    where T : Entity
{
    T entity = await (new Repository<T>()).GetByKeyAsync(args.Id);
    if (entity != null)
        return entity.Content;

    return null;
}
```

Note that you will still need a non-generic method that contains your switch so you choose which path to follow based on `args.CollectionName`. But at least it becomes a lot more concise:

```
private async Task<string> GetByIdFrom(EntityArgs args)
{
    switch (args.CollectionName.ToLowerInvariant())
    {
        case WorkingSite:
            return GetByIdFrom<WorkingSite>(args);
        case ProductInstruction:
            return GetByIdFrom<ProductInstruction>(args);
        case Resource:
            return GetByIdFrom<Resource>(args);
        default:
            Logger.Warn("GetById(): Table {0} not found", args.CollectionName);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to try this. Better yet I'd like to have some kind of `public virtual RepoResolver` method returning correct repository that I could override when unit testing.

Comment: You could do that as well but that won’t exactly help you retrieving the content from the entities. You will probably need an interface for the repositories which returns an entity then; but a repository that returns *just* an entity (instead of a specific subtype) is not really that helpful (apart from accessing the content)