# Inconsistent behavior when using await with dynamic type

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I'm trying to use `dynamic` to go around inconveniences caused by design or lack of it (the "inconvenience" can be found here, if interested [Simplify method retrieving data from generic repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28678668/1061668)).

To make it short, I need to return collection of `Entity` instances. Class is pretty simple:

```
[JsonObject]
public class Entity
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

So `Entity` has only `Id` and `Content`. Inheriting classes might have other properties but I'm only interested about the `Content` part (complex JSON).

All kinds of different entities can be accessed via generic `Repository<T>`. I need to know the `Type` of concrete class because `T` maps to underlying SQLite tables via data provider, built on top of SQLite-net ORM.

So, for example, if I have `Schedule : Entity`, then I'd be using `Repository<Schedule>` to manipulate table named `Schedule`. This part works just fine.

```
// must be instantiated with concrete class/type inheriting
// from Entity in order to map to correct database table
public class Repository<T> where T : new()
{
    public async virtual Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await SQLiteDataProvider.Connection.Table<T>().ToListAsync();
    }
    // etc.
}
```

Main problem is that "commands" are coming from JavaScript client so I'll receive requests in JSON format. In this JSON I have a property called `CollectionName` which specifies the desired table (and the concrete type).

What I need/want is a nice & clean piece of code that can fetch entities from any given table. So, method below was supposed to solve all my problems, but turns out it didn't...

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Entity>> GetAllEntitiesFrom(CollectionArgs args)
{
    // args.CollectionName is type of entity as string
    // namespace + collection name is mapped as correct type
    // e.g. MyNamespace.Schedule
    Type entityType = Type.GetType(
        string.Format("{0}{1}", EntityNamespacePrefix, args.CollectionName), true, true);

    // get correct repository type using resolved entity type
    // e.g. Repository<MyNamespace.Schedule>
    Type repositoryType = typeof(Repository<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
    dynamic repository = Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType);

    // Below `GetAllAsync()` returns `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`.

    // this blocking call works 100%
    //var entities = repository.GetAllAsync().Result;

    // this non-blocking call works when it feels like it
    var entities = await repository.GetAllAsync();

    return entities;
}
```

So if (above) I use blocking `.Result` everything works liek a charm. Instead, if I use `await`, code might or might not work. It really seems to depend on positions of planets and/or mood swings of Flying Spaghetti Monster.

Randomly, but more often than not, given line will be throwing

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter'1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[MyNamespace.Schedule]]'
>   to type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion'.

I'm using .NET 4.0 Extended Framework.

Comment: It wasn't well answered over there - but still - seems like you can avoid dynamic if your Repository<T> type derives from a non generic that can return a deferred (abstract) GetAllAsync that Repository<T> implements.  Then, instead of a dynamic repository you'd have a concrete point to call from.

Comment: Probably you shouldn't be awaiting a dynamic expression here in the first place. What's wrong with `await (Task<IEnumerable<T>>)repository.GetAllAsync()`? That's better because it uses less dynamic.

Comment: There is no `T`, just `Type` resolved at runtime. I don't really know how I'd go about creating equivalent  of `(Task<IEnumerable<Schedule>>)` from `typeof(Schedule)`. And `T` can't be plain `Entity` either (throws exception).

Comment: OK, use `await (Task)...`. Then you can use `dynamic` to extract the result from that task. The less dynamic the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved with 2 dynamic calls:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Entity>> GetAllEntitiesFrom(CollectionArgs args)
{
    var entityType = Type.GetType(
        string.Format("{0}{1}", EntityNamespacePrefix, args.CollectionName), true, true);
    var repositoryType = typeof(Repository<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
    var repository = Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType);
    var task = (Task)((dynamic)repository).GetAllAsync();
    await task;
    var entities = (IEnumerable<Entity>)((dynamic)task).Result;
    return entities;
}
```

**Edit**
Although the above should work, there should be a better overall design. Unfortunately MS decided to use tasks for asynchrony, and since `Task<TResult>` is class, we cannot take benefit from covariance. However, we can do that with the help of a little generic extension with the cost of a little GC garbage. But IMO it greatly simplifies such designs/implementations. Check it out:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Tests
{
    // General async extensions
    public interface IAwaitable<out TResult>
    {
        IAwaiter<TResult> GetAwaiter();
        TResult Result { get; }
    }
    public interface IAwaiter<out TResult> : ICriticalNotifyCompletion, INotifyCompletion
    {
        bool IsCompleted { get; }
        TResult GetResult();
    }
    public static class AsyncExtensions
    {
        public static IAwaitable<TResult> AsAwaitable<TResult>(this Task<TResult> task) { return new TaskAwaitable<TResult>(task); }
        class TaskAwaitable<TResult> : IAwaitable<TResult>, IAwaiter<TResult>
        {
            TaskAwaiter<TResult> taskAwaiter;
            public TaskAwaitable(Task<TResult> task) { taskAwaiter = task.GetAwaiter(); }
            public IAwaiter<TResult> GetAwaiter() { return this; }
            public bool IsCompleted { get { return taskAwaiter.IsCompleted; } }
            public TResult Result { get { return taskAwaiter.GetResult(); } }
            public TResult GetResult() { return taskAwaiter.GetResult(); }
            public void OnCompleted(Action continuation) { taskAwaiter.OnCompleted(continuation); }
            public void UnsafeOnCompleted(Action continuation) { taskAwaiter.UnsafeOnCompleted(continuation); }
        }
    }
    // Your entity framework
    public abstract class Entity
    {
        // ...
    }
    public interface IRepository<out T>
    {
        IAwaitable<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync();
    }
    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Entity
    {
        public IAwaitable<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync() { return GetAllAsyncCore().AsAwaitable(); }
        protected async virtual Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsyncCore()
        {
            //return await SQLiteDataProvider.Connection.Table<T>().ToListAsync();

            // Test
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            return await Task.FromResult(Enumerable.Empty<T>());
        }
    }
    public static class Repository
    {
        public static IAwaitable<IEnumerable<Entity>> GetAllEntitiesFrom(string collectionName)
        {
            var entityType = Type.GetType(typeof(Entity).Namespace + "." + collectionName, true, true);
            var repositoryType = typeof(Repository<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
            var repository = (IRepository<Entity>)Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType);
            return repository.GetAllAsync();
        }
    }
    // Test
    class EntityA : Entity { }
    class EntityB : Entity { }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var t = Test();
            t.Wait();
        }
        static async Task Test()
        {
            var a = await Repository.GetAllEntitiesFrom(typeof(EntityA).Name);
            var b = await Repository.GetAllEntitiesFrom(typeof(EntityB).Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't this be equivalent to my original working but blocking code?

Comment: No - notice the `await task;`.

Comment: In my (unedited) question I was oversimplifying a little bit. My constraint wasn't actually `Entity` but `new()`. Because of this code was breaking randomly. This approach works well, even w/o the edit part you added :)

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I hate using reflection (and dynamic is similar) when there is another way :-)

Comment: True dat. In this case I found myself injecting 12th repository into service, all  `typeof(Repository<T>)` where T might be either strictrly `Entity` or just `new()`, so this was much lesser bad :). All this trouble originated from here http://stackoverflow.com/q/28678668/1061668

Comment: We all do that all the time :-) However note that if `T` does not inherit from `Entity`, `IEnumerable<T>` cannot be cast to `IEnumerable<Entity>` in both approaches. That's why the second approach will protect you at compile time from surprises at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

If the `Repository<T>` type is a type of your own making, you can have it be based on an abstract base type that has an `abstract Task<IEnumerable<Entity>> GetAllAsync()`.  Then, since your Repository apparently already has a method of that signature - so you're good:

```
public abstract class Repository
{
  public abstract Task<IEnumerable<Entity>> GetAllAsync();
}
```

Then have your `Repository<Entity>` be based on Repository.

```
public class Repository<T>: Repository where T: Entity  // Your existing class
{
  public override async Task<IEnumerable<Entity>> GetAllAsync()
  {
    //  Your existing implementation
  }
  //...existing stuff...
}
```

Then, when using it, instead of dynamic, you can say:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Entity>> GetAllEntitiesFrom(CollectionArgs args)
{
  var entityType = 
    Type.GetType(
      string.Format(
        "{0}{1}", 
        EntityNamespacePrefix, 
        args.CollectionName), 
      true, 
      true);

  var repositoryType =
    typeof(Repository<>)
    .MakeGenericType(entityType);

  var repository = 
    (Repository) Activator
    .CreateInstance( repositoryType );

  return repository.GetAllAsync();  // await not required
}
```

No dynamics at all.

Comment: That's fine.  Just have your class be `Repository<T> : Repository where T: Entity`.  I'm (not clearly) saying - two classes: `Repository` and `Repository<T>`.

Comment: This does it, thx, with minor changes. Abstract method declaration can't contain `async` keyword and `GetAllEntitiesFrom` should return `await repository.GetAllAsync()`.

Comment: In my (unedited) question I was oversimplifying a little bit. My constraint wasn't actually `Entity` but `new()`. Because of this code was breaking randomly. Thx for your effort. Still I decided to use approach posted by @Ivan Stoev because it's less of an effort for me (no need to add any abtract/concrete classes).

Comment: Thanks - edited code for posterity.  I should know better than to write stream-of-consciousness into an answer.  I'm just glad this question was rescued from a bad duplicate.  It was worth discussing.